# Matlab engine freezes at MatlabEngi​ne::waitFo​rMatlab when trying to connect

Tags: matlab, qt, matlab-engine, pythonqt

We are trying to use the *matlab engine* in our QT C++ application, through a [PythonQT](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/) console. Normal python commands work from within the pythonQT console in our application, however when we attempt to connect to the matlab engine, it hangs at the function call `MatlabEngine::waitForMATLAB` (see line 6 of stack trace at the end of the question).

We have a Matlab instance running and its engine is shared by calling `matlab.engine.shareEngine`. On the PythonQT console, we connect to it by
`eng = matlab.engine.connect_matlab('XXXX')` .
This results in the engine(?) freezing.

Note: We **don't** have a problem connecting to *matlab engine* directly from a generic python terminal. We only encounter this problem when we access it from within the PythonQT terminal.

#### Stack trace:

```
1  __psynch_cvwait                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
2  _pthread_cond_wait                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
3  std::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l>>>)                                                                                        
4  std::cv_status std::condition_variable::wait_for<long long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l>>(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l>> const&)                                                                                        
5  std::future_status std::__assoc_sub_state::wait_until<std::chrono::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l>>>(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l>>> const&) const     
6  engine_api::waitMATLAB(unsigned long long, double)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
7  MatlabEngine::waitForMATLAB(_object *, _object *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
8  PyEval_EvalFrameEx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
9  ___lldb_unnamed_symbol1476$$Python                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
10 PyEval_EvalFrameEx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
11 PyEval_EvalCodeEx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
12 ___lldb_unnamed_symbol1476$$Python                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
13 PyEval_EvalFrameEx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
14 PyEval_EvalCodeEx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
15 ___lldb_unnamed_symbol1476$$Python                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
16 PyEval_EvalFrameEx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
17 PyEval_EvalCodeEx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
18 ___lldb_unnamed_symbol1476$$Python                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
19 PyEval_EvalFrameEx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
20 PyEval_EvalCodeEx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
21 PyEval_EvalCode                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
22 ___lldb_unnamed_symbol1599$$Python                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
23 PyRun_StringFlags                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
24 PythonQtScriptingConsole::executeCode(QString const&)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
25 PythonQtScriptingConsole::executeLine(bool)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
26 PythonQtScriptingConsole::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
27 QWidget::event(QEvent *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
28 QFrame::event(QEvent *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
29 QAbstractScrollArea::event(QEvent *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
30 QTextEdit::event(QEvent *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
31 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject *, QEvent *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
32 QApplication::notify(QObject *, QEvent *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
33 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject *, QEvent *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
34 ___lldb_unnamed_symbol542$$QtWidgets                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
35 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject *, QEvent *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
36 QApplication::notify(QObject *, QEvent *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
37 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject *, QEvent *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
38 QGuiApplicationPrivate::processKeyEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::KeyEvent *)                                                                                                                                                                                                
39 QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)                                                                                                                                                                                             
40 QWindowSystemInterface::flushWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)                                                                                                                                                                                            
41 ___lldb_unnamed_symbol405$$libqcocoa.dylib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
42 ___lldb_unnamed_symbol406$$libqcocoa.dylib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
43 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:]                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
44 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
45 ___lldb_unnamed_symbol169$$libqcocoa.dylib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
46 ___lldb_unnamed_symbol152$$libqcocoa.dylib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
47 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
48 ___lldb_unnamed_symbol583$$libqcocoa.dylib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
49 -[NSApplication run]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
50 ___lldb_unnamed_symbol505$$libqcocoa.dylib                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
51 QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
52 QCoreApplication::exec()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
53 main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
54 start
```

I have an [open question](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/330051-matlab-engine-freezes-at-matlabengine-waitformatlab-when-trying-to-connect) on this in the Matlab forums, with no answers as of now.

Any help or pointers is appreciated :)

NT

Comment: Never use waits and blocks especially non-Qt on the main thread which is loaded enough with Qt frameworks callbacks.

Comment: Thanks. We tried calling the connect_matlab() call from a QThread, but it still hangs.

Comment: Either it is not running on the worker thread or something else is preventing main thread from running. From the stack of the crash you provided only the main thread seen and that is not the source code. I suspect the code being incorrect then.